# Creation of a DAG on a network?

Tags: iota-network

How to contribute to DAG like how you can mine in a blockchain? I have read that DAG does not use electricity like blockchain,  so how is it created,  not using computer resources?

Comment: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/iota-full-node-network?s=8|13.4245

Answer (score 1):

In IOTA there are no miners.
If you want to broadcast your transaction to the network (to the Tangle) you have to confirm two other transactions. This means that there is no distinction between those who "make" the transaction and those who "approve" the transactions.
The more people participate issuing transactions, the faster the confirmation will be.

In conclusion: if you want to help the network just start using IOTA! You have two "basic" options:

- **light node**: download the official wallet (in the next month the new version will be released), connect to a full node (there is a list on [IOTA support](https://iotasupport.com/lightwallet.shtml)) and start making transaction;
- **full node**: creating a full node you'll make the network larger and contribute actively to the growth of IOTA (look for tutorials to know how to setup a full node).

There are also new ways of joining the network but I'm not yet informed about them (CarrIota, Nelson,...).

Let me know if I should explain something better!